# Jetpack Compose tilted row with buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm developing an Android app in Jetpack Compose, which is basically a big form. I wanted to add a little style to it with custom buttons, but I don't really know how to make them.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Example button style]

In that layout there will be 2 Buttons with a TextField in the middle. How can I tilt them so it looks like the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a custom shape like this:

```
class ParallelogramShape(private val angle: Float): Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density,
    ) = Outline.Generic(
        Path().apply {
            val width = size.width - size.height / tan(angle)
            moveTo(size.width - width, 0f)
            lineTo(size.width, 0f)
            lineTo(width, size.height)
            lineTo(0f, size.height)
            lineTo(size.width - width, 0f)
        }
    )
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black)
val shape = ParallelogramShape(45f)
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .border(border, shape = shape)
) {
    var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(10) }
    TextButton(
        onClick = { counter -= 1 },
        shape = shape,
        border = border,
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(45.dp)
            .width(100.dp)
    ) {
        Text("-")
    }
    Text(counter.toString())
    TextButton(
        onClick = { counter += 1 },
        shape = shape,
        border = border,
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(45.dp)
            .width(100.dp)
    ) {
        Text("+")
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]